# how can I get specific columns in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to get specific columns from textfile 
I read the file but I can't access columns 
like: I want col4, col6....
any help?

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
 [filename pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt'}, 'File Selector');
 inputfile = fopen(filename); 
delimiter = ','; headers = 1; 
 values = importdata(filename, delimiter, headers);
 disp(values);
```

Comment: how does your textfile look like? Why can't you access the columns? how about: `values(:,4)` ?

Comment: the file have 128*7 rows and 22 cols 
I tried values(:,4);
there was an error told me ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: What does `size(values)` return?  Is the data all numbers, or a mix of numbers and strings?

Comment: you should provide a sample file, otherwise it is hard to guess how the import needs to be done

Comment: the first row is header Strings otherwise all numbers between each col is comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `filname` is the path to a textfile then `importdata(filename)` returns a struct

```
{
    data
    textdata
    colheaders
}
```

The values are stored in `values.data`. Use `values.data(:,[4 6])`.